# Sequilize association for 2 foriegn key of same model

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I need to execute below query using sequelize

```
SELECT * FROM haulerrfquotes
LEFT JOIN quotes ON quotes.jobId = haulerrfquotes.jobId AND haulerrfquotes.haulerId = quotes.haulerId
WHERE haulerrfquotes.jobId = '11'
```

But i am not getting how to use two foriegn keys in same model(haulerrfquotes) and to create association of both foriegn keys to single model (quotes)

Answer (score 1):

In sequelize, you could define your own join condition by supplying the `on` options in the include object. Here's an example to perform the query in question

```
haulerrfquotes.findAll({
    where: {
        jobId: 11
    },
    include: [{
        model: quotes,
        required: false,
        on: {
            jobId: {
                $col: 'haulerrfquotes.jobId'
            },
            haulerId: {
                $col: 'haulerrfquotes.haulerId'
            }
        }
    }]
}).then(result => {
    // The rest of your logic here...
});
```